# Mapserver and postgis

Tags: postgis, mapserver, query

Here is the relevant portion of my mapfile:

```
CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS  
  CONNECTION "dbname=contours host=localhost user=contour_xxxx password=xxx"  
  PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"  
  DATA "wkb_geometry from contours USING UNIQUE ogc_fid USING
contourinterval=40"
```

I want to limit the contours returned to only include `contourinterval=40`.
As you can see from the Postgres log (below), contourinterval isn't even
referenced in the query...

```
select
    "contourelevation",
    encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force2D("wkb_geometry"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,
    "ogc_fid" 
from contours 
where wkb_geometry &&
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-111.939697265625
33.4213636331582,-111.939697265625 33.4323499612832,-111.9287109375
33.4323499612832,-111.9287109375 33.4213636331582,-111.939697265625
33.4213636331582))',find_srid('','contours','wkb_geometry'))
```

I've tried all sorts of subselects and examples found on the web, nothing
works. BTW, I assume 'contourelevation' is pulled because it is my
LABELITEM. The data is USGS contour data.

Comment: If you want return only the rows where contourinterval = 40, you need to use a WHERE.  DATA "wkb_geometry from contours where contourinterval = 40 USING UNIQUE ogc_fid". If you try "SELECT wkb_geometry FROM contours WHERE contourinterval = 40" in PGAdmin, what does it do?

Answer (score 5):

If you want Mapserver to use only the rows where contourinterval = 40, you need to use a WHERE.

I think you should use this connection string instead:

```
CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS  
CONNECTION "dbname=contours host=localhost user=contour_xxxx password=xxx"   
DATA "wkb_geometry FROM contours WHERE contourinterval = 40 USING UNIQUE ogc_fid".
```

Also, make sure the request actually works.

In PGAdmin, try:

```
SELECT wkb_geometry FROM contours WHERE contourinterval = 40
```

Make it work outside Mapserver first. Then, you should check the Mapserver logs.

To debug, try setting the log level to 5 (it's in the MAP object).

```
MAP
  ...
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "ms_error.txt"
  DEBUG 5
  ...
  LAYER
    ...
  END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback! Turns out, there were no contourinterval = 40 rows within the bounding box area I was selecting. The Mapserver documentation wasn't clear how the 'using xxx' clause translated into the actual SQL statement. I was assuming it built a 'where' clause with any values stated.